# Can I load AMD modules inside a webworker?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, web-worker, js-amd

I am trying out webworkers for making my computationally heavy Javascript truly parallel.  However, I have a problem in that all of my javascript files are AMD modules.  Can I use requirejs inside of my webworker?  How?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Web workers, other scripts can be loaded using the [`importScripts` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_web_workers#Importing_scripts_and_libraries). The [source code of RequireJS](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/blob/master/require.js#L23) shows that Web workers are also supported:

```
// Line 23:
isWebWorker = !isBrowser && typeof importScripts !== 'undefined',
// Line 1877:
} else if (isWebWorker) {
    //In a web worker, use importScripts. This is not a very
    //efficient use of importScripts, importScripts will block until
    //its script is downloaded and evaluated. However, if web workers
    //are in play, the expectation that a build has been done so that
    //only one script needs to be loaded anyway. This may need to be
    //reevaluated if other use cases become common.
    importScripts(url);
```

Comment: So, just to be clear...first I call importScripts('require.js'); and on the next line I do require([...], function(...) { ... }); ?

Comment: And also, presumably, you can also configure your require call using the options?

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg `requireJS` should include the script (see the link to the source code in the answer). Go try it, and report back ;)

Comment: In the middle of trying it.  Also found this in the requirejs documentation.  For some reason, my search engine didn't pick it up: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#webworker

Comment: I wrote a short library that uses requirejs to load AMD modules inside of the worker context and called it [HardWorker](https://github.com/aressler38/HardWorker).